# timeago in flutter never changes locale/language from english

Tags: flutter, dart, timeago

i tried to add locales "Arabic AR" in timeago package for flutter/Dart and it never changes from english, i can't see for example: 1 hour ago in arabic, it only showing in english, although app is RTL. What should i do for getting months,hours, weeks, years ago with translation in arabic? please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

you should call `setLocaleMessages` first

```
 timeago.setLocaleMessages('ar', timeago.ArMessages());
```

or you can use custom locale

```
timeago.setLocaleMessages('ar', MyCustomMessages());


// my_custom_messages.dart
class MyCustomMessages implements LookupMessages {
  @override String prefixAgo() => '';
  @override String prefixFromNow() => '';
  @override String suffixAgo() => '';
  @override String suffixFromNow() => '';
  @override String lessThanOneMinute(int seconds) => 'الآن';
  @override String aboutAMinute(int minutes) => '${minutes}د';
  @override String minutes(int minutes) => '${minutes}د';
  @override String aboutAnHour(int minutes) => '${minutes}س';
  @override String hours(int hours) => '${hours}ساعة';
  @override String aDay(int hours) => '${hours}ساعات';
  @override String days(int days) => '${days}يوم';
  @override String aboutAMonth(int days) => '${days}أيام';
  @override String months(int months) => '${months}شهر';
  @override String aboutAYear(int year) => '${year}سنة';
  @override String years(int years) => '${years}سنوات';
  @override String wordSeparator() => ' ';
}
```

You can Custom this code as you like

Good Luck